# How to best type an object with multiple types for values

Tags: typescript

Hi and thank you in advance.

My goal is to create a UI component that accepts boolean and string style props. However I get the error below due to the `Styles` type containing the `bg` prop which accepts a `string`. I tried various methods to solve this using a `Record` type, but since the check happens at runtime, it wasnt helpful.

The error occurs at `stylesProps[k as keyof StyleProps]`. What is best practice for addressing this error?

As a separate questions, is an array of keys to loop the best way to loop through expected keys of a type? That require updating the code in two locations for adding more properties in the future, I was trying to reduce it to a single location.

```
"Type 'string | boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)"
```

```
// .tsx
// styles props
const keys = ["block", "center", "row", "column", "border", "bg"];

type Styles = {
  block: boolean;
  center: boolean;
  row: boolean;
  column: boolean;
  border: boolean;
  bg: string;
};

type AllowedStyles = Partial<Styles>;

// component props
type Props = Partial<
  AllowedStyles & { children: JSXElement | JSXElement[] | undefined }
>;

// utilities
// this function will take in component props and return an object containing just the [k,v] of style props
const getBoxStyleProps = (props: Props): AllowedStyles => {
  let stylesProps: AllowedStyles = {};

  for (let k of keys) {
    stylesProps[k as keyof AllowedStyles] = props[k as keyof AllowedStyles];
//  ^-----------------------------------^ TS err
  }

  return stylesProps;
};

// more code, not included
```

```
//.jsx using component here with allowed style props
export default function Index() {
  return (
    <Box block column border bg="blue">
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by this : `but since the check happens at runtime, it wasnt helpful` ?

Comment: @TusharShahi perhaps my understanding is incorrect, but since `for (let k of keys)` is happening during runtime and not during compilation, I was unable to successfully do type checking as we are looping through a dynamic object (Component props)

Comment: Is this what you need? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gUwJ4RgXhgbQEQCMA2Iwc2ANDNsAmFAgE5kV0gDujlI+ArgLZju4QdACb0BAc2wBdGAENUoSFADcAKFVQkABwQwAypvwJUGAN6qYMAkTgAuKyE4JZYNZao169wU5duYzCzejkZ+FjCg3HzBvq7hgiJeDrH+uOL2mjogAGbwyBCYYLy49FJqAL5qqkA

Comment: @TusharShahi No, the keys are a separate and less important question.  For the primary concern `bg` has to accept only a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries`, filtering the keys:

```
const getBoxStyleProps = (props: Props): AllowedStyles => {
  let stylesProps: AllowedStyles = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(props).filter(([key]) => keys.includes(key)));

  return stylesProps;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gUwJ4RgXhgbQEQCMA2Iwc2ANDNsAmFAgE5kV0gDujlI+ArgLZju4QdACb0BAc2wBdANwBYAFCKoSAA4IYAZRX4EqDAG9FMGASJwAXKZCcEAQzDyFJqjXpXBth05PMWHm11vYxhQbj4Ar0cQwRF3ayifU3EraDoASzBxJwBfJ2U1DQBBfEIWBGFtJF19GAAFOzoodLt8AB4qmoA+fIUAej7QkB5VcGpYVWZVCAL1eqnahqaW9pCSsorOvRgAMhgDUIALdPxhOmorAClNAA0AOgBRXR5xmAAfGGv7p4QXmkwpO8YFwwKIAGaZCowHKKHqKRQDYHNfDpZp6BGDKDHVBgkHAZrgGAsE74GBQOyIGCZIYjMY0GCTEDTGAOYQwc5QLh0MAsnkgXAAKwQ+KGNDsmUy4hgAq40DJhw0mDgpAAboCQGCYNBqhpGdNFKBILBxAgoAAhEAADy2dQW6BgAAo9RArLamRAAJRWdasTY6bZoLr7EK6WDampu6be0q+yr+2oAeUFwqgdzBzB4DxoGT0DqTQvxd3GOYgToWHrTJ1odAdDqVyCkHvQQcQKDumWA3FEpdbHr7vV8pq5PPDekjEFyMiAA)

---

note: this is one of the more loosely typed solutions

---

You can also get fancier with a generic:

```
const getBoxStyleProps = <K extends keyof Styles>(props: Props, keys: K[]): { [P in K]: Styles[P] } => {
  let stylesProps = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(props).filter(([key]) => keys.includes(key as K)));

  return stylesProps as { [P in K]: Styles[P] } ;
};

const v = getBoxStyleProps(props, ["block", "center"]);
//    ^? { block: boolean; center: boolean }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gUwJ4RgXhgbQEQCMA2Iwc2ANDNsAmFAgE5kV0gDujlI+ArgLZju4QdACb0BAc2wBdGAENUoSFADcAWABQGqEgAOCGAGVt+BKgwBvDTBgEicAFw2QnBLLBr11qjXqPBLtw9rZhY-ZxNAqxhQbj4wgPcowRFfJwSgm3FHaDoASzBxDwBfDy1dfQBBfEIWBGEjJBMzGAAFWTooXNl8AB4GpoA+UvUAehHokB4dcGpYHWYdCDK9VoXmto6u3qiqmrr+0xgAMhhzaIALXPxhOmpHACkDAA0AOgBREx5ZmAAfGEfXh8EF8aJgZH8uGBRAAzfJ1GBFDRDDQaMYwLidfC5TqmVHjKCXVDQyHATrgGAsK74GBQWSIGD5CZTGY0GDzECLORQmC3KBcOhgLkwEC4ABWCFJExosny+XEMFFXGgNPO+kwcFIADcZCBoTBoI19OzFhpFMrxAgoAAhEAADwOLTW6BgPQA0jAELbaFDUIgkLrDMZTAMABTGiCOR0ciDkP0RmCusEASkcZ0wLQZgtdUkcBwg6ZkRXQA1OURMsANTSjnIwAHkxRKoC9ocweG8aHlTCH6+LSS9Zp2IGG1knm1daHQQyH1cgpEni-BkBAXvlgNxREO-XJUK6k3vhsFLfzBZXTNXUPJTlgM4zs7mg-mWoWYMVlEA)

Comment: This is helpful, thank you @vr can I ask you to explain why my original code wasnt sufficient?  Im trying to understand the TS compiler better.

Comment: @Pmcorrea Pretend I have two boxes, one which can only hold apples (`AppleBox`), and the other which can only hold oranges (`OrangeBox`). Let's say there is another box, and I don't know if it is either an apple box or orange box, but I know for sure it is one of the two (`AppleBox | OrangeBox`). To put something in this new box *safely*, I somehow have to put in something that is both an apple and an orange (which is impossible), since if I put in an apple and it's actually an orange box, I have placed the item in the wrong box, and vice versa. Do you understand my analogy?

Comment: I do, thank you, to be more specific, why doesn't the compiler recognize that `stylesProps` is of type `AllowedStyles` and thus allow me to put any property from `stylesProps[k as keyof AllowedStyles] = props[k as keyof AllowedStyles];` ? Did I properly use the `as keyof` keywords in both sides of the assignment?

Comment: @Pmcorrea The problem is that TS doesn't see this as (using => to denote assignment) `(X => X) | (Y => Y) | (Z => Z)`, but rather `X | Y | Z => X | Y | Z`, which is unsafe, since you may be assigning an X to a Z and so on.